# Will an app which checks for JB be rejected?

Tags: ios, app-store

do you thing that an app which checks for JB will be rejected by Apple?

My concern is that when they see a word like "jailbreak" they will decline my approval request.

The idea is to check whether or not the device is jailbroken.
And also to verify system integrity like are there any strange .bundle installed etc.

Comment: nope, it will be not rejected in general – but you can do certain things what may violate thew review guideline during JB detection.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be rejected for that reason. I have many apps that check for jail broken devices by trying to open 'Cydia' etc. I get warnings in my console to tell me that's not allowed however my apps have not been rejected because of it.

Answer (score 0):

[HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/) is a widely used crash reporting tool and it checks. No issues with it in dozens of apps.

[image]